# Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render at useSelector

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a featured pool in a react app where I am finding the vault with the highest APY reward through an API. I want to fetch some details after we have found the exact pool. But I am getting this error in on one of the statements.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEh5C.png)

This is the code for the FeaturedPool:

```js
export const FeaturedPool = () => {
  // @ts-ignore
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [APY, setAPY] = useState("");
  const [Liquidity, setLiquidity] = useState("");
  const [userPos, setUserPos] = useState("----");

  const [tvlId, setTvlId] = useState<String | undefined>("----");

  // @ts-ignore
  let poolsArray = {};
  const [poolDetails, setPoolDetails] = useState<PoolInfo | undefined>();

  useEffect(() => {
    let counter = 0;
    POOLS?.filter((x) => x.stableCoins)?.map((pool) => {
      // @ts-ignore
      poolsArray[pool.targetedAPYId] = "";
      fetch("https://yields.llama.fi/chart/" + pool.targetedAPYId)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((res) => {
          let result = res.data.at(-1).apyReward.toFixed(2);
          // @ts-ignore
          poolsArray[pool.targetedAPYId] = result;
          counter++;
          if (counter == 3) {
            console.log("ALL 3 FETCHED");
            let arr = Object.values(poolsArray);

            // @ts-ignore
            let max = Math.max(...arr);
            const poolKey =
              // @ts-ignore
              Object.keys(poolsArray).find((key) => poolsArray[key] == max);
            // ts-ignore
            setPoolDetails(POOLS.find((x) => x.targetedAPYId == poolKey));

            console.log(poolDetails);
            if (poolDetails) {
              console.log(poolDetails?.tvlId);
              setTvlId(poolDetails?.tvlId);
              if (tvlId != "----") {
                fetchLiquidityData(tvlId);
              }
            }

            setAPY(String(max));
            // setUserPosition(useVault(poolDetails?.id as string));
            // console.log("User POS:", userPosition);
            setLoading(false);
          }
        });
    });
  }, []);

  const wallet = useWallet();
  const app = useApp();

  if (poolDetails) {
    if (poolDetails?.id) {
**THIS IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM**
      const { userPosition } = useVault(poolDetails?.id);
      // setUserPos(poolDetails?.id);
      console.log(userPosition);
    }
  }

  const fetchLiquidityData = (liqId: any) => {
    if (liqId != "") {
      console.log("LIQ DATA", liqId);
      fetch("https://yields.llama.fi/chart/" + liqId)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((res) => {
          let liq =
            (Math.abs(Number(res.data.at(-1).tvlUsd)) / 1.0e6).toFixed(2) + "M";
          console.log(liq);

          setLiquidity(liq);
        });
    }
  };

  const handleVaultIcon = (title: any) => {
    return title.toLowerCase() === "quick vault" ? true : false;
  };

  return (
    <>
      {!loading ? (<p>Loaded</p>) : <p>Not Loaded</p>}
<>
);
```

This is the Pools structure in the constants file:

```js
export type PoolInfo = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  icon: string;
  score: number;
  risk: string;
  apyRange: string;
  targetedAPYId?: string;
  targetedAPY: string;
  tvlId?: string;
  strategy: string;
  vaultAddress: string;
  strategyAddress: string;
  zapAddress: string;
  isRetired?: boolean;
  stableCoins?: boolean;
  wantToken: string;
  isOld?: boolean;
  details?: string;
  benefits?: string[];
  promptTokens?: Token[];
};

export const POOLS: PoolInfo[] = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "Stablecoins - BUSD (Retired)",
    description: `Akin to bank's savings a/c but superior low risk yields via USD stables investments`,
    icon: "/assets/pools/stables.png",
    score: 0,
    risk: "Ultra-Low Risk",
    apyRange: "0%",
    targetedAPY: "0",
    strategy: "BUSD LP",
    vaultAddress: "0xbA8558121F76577368c624236F9Aa6Db5c877C96",
    strategyAddress: "0x1753877530EC6D691716932757E02Da3b49E247b",
    zapAddress: "0x9D7040C22618F8FAf7509892276274207A576392",
    wantToken: "BUSD",
    isRetired: true,
    stableCoins: false,
    isOld: true,
  }
```

Please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: You shouldn't call your hooks conditionally from within `if` blocks.

Comment: From the React Rules of Hooks (https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning#breaking-rules-of-hooks): "Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions." You're calling a hook inside a condition, therefore you are breaking the Rules of Hooks, therefore you can expect problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot do this as mentioned in the comments section, I see that you want to be sure `poolDetails?.id` is defined before you call `useVault`, but this is not possible.

hooks are usually designed to accept `undefined` and handle it, therefore, without checking just put:

```js
const { userPosition } = useVault(poolDetails?.id);
```

**update after op comment:**

If the argument should be of type `string` then you can handle it this way:

```js
const { userPosition } = useVault(poolDetails?.id ? poolDetails?.id : '');
```

Comment: This approach gives me error. "Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'"

Comment: @AnayaAmmar have a look I updated my answer